# XSLT: Adding an XML Hyperlink to Another XML Value

Tags: xml, pdf-generation, xsl-fo

I am trying to hyperlink a value. The hyperlink itself is stored in the XML as well. This is used to output a pdf's line items.

This is my current code:

```
<fo:block font-size="8pt">
  <fo:inline>
    <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(_preload_product_id, &quot; - &quot;)" />
  </fo:inline>
</fo:block>
```

I want to be able to add a hyperlink to the substring. The actual url link, like I mentioned, comes from the XML as well so it looks like this for my XSL:

```
<xsl:value-of select="cf_customer_quotation_line_item_product_url" />
```

I have been looking around but I usually find code more geared to websites, but I am doing a PDF. 
I would also like to know if it possible to add this same hyperlink to an image like below:

```
<fo:block>
     <fo:external-graphic src="url()" content-height="2cm">
            <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="cf_customer_quotation_line_item_image_url"/>
            </xsl:attribute>                                        
     </fo:external-graphic>
</fo:block>
```

Comment: What rendering engine are you using?  It may be a feature of that product.  I'll see what the one I uses offers and get back to you.

Comment: Entirely not sure but this PDF is produced in a product called Workbooks CRM.

xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your image (or whatever else you want to become a link) in a `fo:basic-link`

For example:

```
<fo:block>
     <fo:basic-link external-link="url(--url to link destination--)">
       <fo:external-graphic src="url(--url to image--)" content-height="2cm" />
     </fo:basic-link>    
</fo:block>
```

To use some concrete values as an example.  I have an image on my hard drive `d:\images\smiley.jpg`.  The URL of the hyperlink's destination is in an element accessible from your xsl named `cf_customer_quotation_line_item_product_url` (as in your example), the above becomes:

```
<fo:block>
     <fo:basic-link external-link="url({cf_customer_quotation_line_item_product_url})">
       <fo:external-graphic src="url(d:\images\smiley.jpg)" content-height="2cm" />
     </fo:basic-link>    
</fo:block>
```

The curly brackets in the `external-link`s url() value cause an evaluation kind of like `value-of` but inside an attribute.

Further edit (based on your reply):

Change this

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:basic-link>
    <xsl:attribute name="external-destination">
    <xsl:value-of select="cf_customer_quotation_line_item_product_url"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
        <fo:external-graphic src="url()" content-height="2cm">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
        <xsl:value-of select="cf_customer_quotation_line_item_image_url"/>
        </xsl:attribute>                                        
        </fo:external-graphic>
    </fo:basic-link>
</fo:block>
```

to this

```
<fo:block>
    <fo:basic-link external-destination="url({cf_customer_quotation_line_item_product_url})" text-altitude="2cm">
        <fo:external-graphic src="url({cf_customer_quotation_line_item_image_url})" content-height="2cm" />
    </fo:basic-link>
</fo:block>
```

If you find that still doesn't work, try clicking at the bottom of the image - it may be the hypertext region is only "text high".  If that is happening for you, add a `text-altitude` to the `fo:basic-link` the same height as your image (I've updated the example above).

Comment: Biscuit, 
I replaced my code with yours and it works the same as my code meaning, the image is not hyperlinked. The image still shows though,  so at least that did not break.

Comment: @idxearo I did yet another edit.  With your code as is, does the link appear at the bottom of your image?  If so, add the `text-altitude` to the link.

Comment: You were initially correct, that the "link" is below the image at a small, small area. I have added the text-altitude as you have amended, but this does not work. I believe I may have read somewhere that text-altitude does not work on PDFS (unsure the correct words for engine/type of XSL that PDFs use). Is there a different syntax for this altitude attribute?

Edit-something called FOP, text-altitude does not work

Comment: You may be stuck unless you switch renderers.  I see that `text-attribute` is also not supported by FOP (as of 2011), but it is supported by RenderX XEP - which is what I use (http://www.renderx.com/tools/xep.html).  If you can't switch tools, and if you can't resize your images to fit inside the hyperlink zone in PDF - maybe add a "Click me" button image beside the actual image, one just high enough to be covered by the hyperlink zone.

Comment: @idxearo The only other thing I can suggest exploring:  Maybe you can post-process the PDF.  I note in my testing the only difference between using `text-attribute` and not is the `Rect` value of the `<</Subtype/Link/Border...>>` element.  There may be free PDF tools that can help - or maybe you can create a script something to adjust the `Rect` values - esp. if all images are the same height.

Comment: @idxearo If you want more details on post-processing, ask another question and add a comment here with a link to it.

Comment: Thanks biscuit, I wont hurt my head anymore on the issue as I think it is stuck there. I don't have any control over the render engines as the system outputting the pdfs is cloud based. I will just add a simple "View Product Page". Thanks you again for the help